# ’ character being converted to â€™ in jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to read a UTF-8 string from my MySql database, which I create using:

```
CREATE DATABASE april
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I make the table of interest using:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `article`;
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` longtext NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

If I  `select * from article` in the MySql command line util, I get:

```
OIL sands output at Nexen’s Long Lake project dropped in February.
```

However, when I do

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(QUERY);

long id = -1;
String text = null;
Timestamp date = null;
while (rs.next()) {
    text = rs.getString("text");
    LOGGER.debug("text=" text);
}
```

the output I get is:

```
text=OIL sands output at Nexenâ€™s Long Lake project dropped in February.
```

I get my Connection via:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:" + this.dbms + "://" + this.serverHost + ":" + this.serverPort + "/" + this.dbName + "?useUnicode&user=" + this.username + "&password=" + this.password);
```

I've also tried, instead of the `useUnicode` parameter:

```
characterEncoding=UTF-8
and
characterEncoding=utf8
```

I also tried, instead of the line `text = rs.getString("text")`

```
rs.getBytes("text");
String[] encodings = new String[]{"US-ASCII", "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", "UTF-16BE", "UTF-16LE", "UTF-16", "Latin1"};
for (String encoding : encodings) {
    text = new String(temp, encoding);
    LOGGER.debug(encoding + ": " + text);
}
// Which outputted:
US-ASCII: OIL sands output at Nexen��������s Long Lake project dropped in February.
ISO-8859-1: OIL sands output at NexenÃ¢â¬â¢s Long Lake project dropped in February.
UTF-8: OIL sands output at Nexenâ€™s Long Lake project dropped in February.
UTF-16BE: 佉䰠獡湤猠潵瑰畴⁡琠乥硥滃ꋢ芬ꉳ⁌潮朠䱡步⁰牯橥捴⁤牯灰敤⁩渠䙥扲畡特�
UTF-16LE: 䥏⁌慳摮⁳畯灴瑵愠⁴敎數썮겂蓢玢䰠湯⁧慌敫瀠潲敪瑣搠潲灰摥椠⁮敆牢慵祲�
UTF-16: 佉䰠獡湤猠潵瑰畴⁡琠乥硥滃ꋢ芬ꉳ⁌潮朠䱡步⁰牯橥捴⁤牯灰敤⁩渠䙥扲畡特�
Latin1: OIL sands output at NexenÃ¢â¬â¢s Long Lake project dropped in February.
```

I load the strings into the DB using some pre-defined sql in a file. This file is UTF-8 encoded.

```
mysql -u april -p -D april < insert_articles.sql
```

This file includes the line:

```
 INSERT INTO article (text) value ("OIL sands output at Nexen’s Long Lake project dropped in February.");
```

When I print out that file within my application using:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/home/path/to/file/sql_article_inserts.sql")));
 String str;
 while((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     LOGGER.debug("LINE: " + str);
 }
```

I get the correct, expected output:

```
LINE: INSERT INTO article (text) value ("OIL sands output at Nexen’s Long Lake project dropped in February.");
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Some System Details:
I am running on linux (Ubuntu)

Edits:
* Edited to specify OS
* Edited to detail output of reading sql input file.
* Edited to specify more about how the data is inserted into the DB.
* Edited to to fix typo in code, and clarify example.

Comment: LOGGER is an instance of: org.apache.log4j.Logger

Comment: Nope, did that, and it seems I'm running UTF-8: System.getProperty("file.encoding")= 'UTF-8'

Comment: The line : text = new String(temp, encoding);  will only f-u the string more.  The encoding to change is the one the LOGGER uses.

Comment: @KarIP - you're absolutely correct, that was a typo - I've fixed the question. I was using the new String() method on the byte-array that rs.getBytes("text") returned, and only to see if it would produce the correct output - which it didn't - as you say, in most cases, it made it worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible you're reading the log file using the incorrect encoding? windows-1252, I am guessing.

```
UTF-8: OIL sands output at Nexenâ€™s Long Lake project dropped in February.
```

If this is appearing in the log, do a hex dump of the log file. If the data is UTF-8, you would expect the sequence `Nexen’s` to become `4E 65 78 65 6E E2 80 99 73`. If some other application reads this as a native ANSI encoding, it'll decode it as `Nexenâ€™s`.

To confirm, you can also dump the individual characters of the return value to see if they are correct in UTF-16:

```
//untested
for(char ch : text.toCharArray()) {
   System.out.printf("%04x%n", (int) ch);
}
```

I'm assuming all data is in the [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane), so you can just look up the results in the [Unicode charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).

Comment: I doubt it's windows-1252, as I'm running linux (Ubuntu). I'll dump the string to HEX, and post it here.

Comment: HEX of re.getBytes("text"): 4e6578656ec3a2e282ace284a273204c6f6e67204c616b652070726f6a6563742064726f7070656420696e2046656272756172792e. I found the 4E6578656E you specified, it starts: 4e6578656e__c3a2e282ace284a27320...

Comment: So looks like it's wrong in that case ... so coming from the DB NOT as UTF-8.

Comment: @barryred - that hex sequence is valid UTF-8 containing the 3 code points `â` (c3 a2) `€` (e2 82 ac) `™` (e2 84 a2). It looks like the data is being encoded as UTF-8 twice. I would say the record was corrupt - except that it is OK when you query it using MySQL tools.

Comment: Decided to try inserting it differently (using java instead of the command line) and now I'm getting: "java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\x92s Lon...' for column 'text' at row 1." A bit of googling tells me that \x92 is the ' character in windows-1252. Seems you were on the money at the start. Now to figure out why my file is encoded that way, but says it's encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Seems that the file must have been windows-1252, and => the data in the DB which it fed was also windows-1252. Not sure why, since I'm running on linux, but it's resolved now (by fixing the data in the DB). Thanks.

Comment: Linux tips : Use "file insert_articles.sql" to get a guess of the encoding. (btw, cp1252 and iso-8859-1 are almost identical) Convert using "iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 <test1.txt >test2.txt"

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the database itself to UTF-8.  When creating the DB:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Also see [MySQL reference on connection charsets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) and [MySQL reference on configuring charsets for applications](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html)

Comment: I had already created the database with 'DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8', and have now recreated it with 'DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci', but no luck. I@ll have a read of those references and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in the JDBC URL only define how the driver should communicate with the server. If the server does not use UTF8 by default these parameters won't change it either.

Have you tried executing the following SQL query after connecting? (This should switch the current connection to UTF8 on the server-side too):

```
SET names utf8
```

Comment: Tried this, after I got a connection: 
{
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("SET names utf8");
}
But no luck - still returns incorrectly.
How do I check what encoding the server has the table/field in?

Answer (score 0):

There are several character encodings involved.

- The terminal/cmd window that the mysql command line tool is running. (putty?)
- the environment in the shell (bash) where you are running your stuff. (LC_CTYPE)
- Mysql internal (used in tables) : you have defined this to UTF-8
- The JVM internal (always UTF16)
- The character used by the writers the logger use. Default (system property) or perhaps defined in the logging frameworks configuration.
- The terminal/cmd/editor that you read the logs with. ( putty/bash?)

If the terminal settings are wrong, you might have inserted corrupted data in mysql. (If your terminal is iso-8859-1 and you read a file that is UTF-8, for instance) Assuming linux, mysql should look at the env LC_CTYPE (but I am not 100% sure that it does.)

The JDBCD driver is responsible for converting the database character encoding to the JVMs internal format (UTF16) so that should not be a problem. But you can test this with a simpel java program that inserts a hard coded string, and reads it back. Print the original and received string - they should be identical. But; ***If both are wrong,*** you have a problem with the terminals character set definition.

Use a string like "HejÅÄÖ" for some drama...

ALso, write a small program that prints the same string to a file using a printwriter that converts to UTF-8 and verify that the tool you use for reading the log prints that file correctly. If not, there terminals settings are to be suspected, again.

```
String test = "Test HEJ \u00C5\u00C4\u00D6 ÅÄÖ";
 // here's how to define what character set to use when writing to a fileOutputStream
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("test.txt","UTF8");
pw.println(test);
pw.flush();
pw.close();
System.out.println(test);
```

output -> Test HEJ ÅÄÖ ÅÄÖ

The contents ni the file test.txt should look the same.

Comment: I edited the end of my question with the results, but looks like the LOGGER is reading the characters correctly.

Comment: Also, I can see it, so the terminal can display the characters correctly too.